# Arduino - making a ringing tone but its not accurate

Tags: c++, arduino, ringtone, arduino-yun

Arduino, i am trying to make ring tone (like brrr brrr, brrr brrr, old common telephone ring tone), but i am not even close to it yet. Can anyone show me how you do it?

```
void play_on() { // this should play exact telephony ring tone, but how?
  for(int i=0; i <50; i++) {
    tone(2, i+900, i+10);  
    delay(60);              
    noTone(2);

  }    
}
```

Comment: Maybe use a sampled tone rather than trying to generate it from scratch ?

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12735/is-there-a-way-to-play-sounds-from-an-arduino-without-using-a-sound-shield

Comment: explain routines **tone** and **noTone**

Comment: Here is tone and noTone explained: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone